# Issue related to lost focus in Textbox when RequiredValidator is used

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net Web Application, i have login screen in Application.

In userName and password field i have used required field validator as follows :

```
 <td style="width: 160px">
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserNm" runat="server" CssClass="txtSingleline txtBack-Color txtRequireBorder-Color required"                                                     Height="18px" Width="150px"  TabIndex="1" MaxLength="50" onblur="ValidatorOnChange(event);showhide();"></asp:TextBox>
 </td>
<td style="width: 140px">
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" 
Width="150px" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="Please enter Username" ControlToValidate="txtUserNm"                                                 ValidationGroup="a"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

when i focus on UserName textbox and Press Tab , i am unable to loos the focus from the TextBox because of RequiredField Validator. it happens only in Chrome and IE9 . but working well in firefox.

what can be solution to loose the focus from the Textbox when using Requiredfield validator ???

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple... just remove the `SetFocusOnError="true"` or set it to `false`.

The only downside is you can only validate the form on form post back, not on the fly. 
But, it's not even such a pain in the neck, since even if you remove this property, validation works fine in both normal web forms, and ajax update panels.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you should manually assign `tabindex` [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.tabindex.aspx) to your controls in order to define loop by pressing tab.